# Powering D1 Mini through 5V pin

Tags: esp8266, switching-regulator

I am trying to power a D1 mini (ESP8266) through the 5V pin (not using USB port).

I have a 9V transformer connected to a 5V Regulator ([5V Regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09N6Y8YYN))

I have set the regulator at 5.42V when there is no load applied. As soon as I plug in the D1 mini using the 5V and Ground pins, the voltage drops to 4.57V.

The problem is that the D1 mini does not seem to finish the booting process. If I test the voltage at the 3V pin it measures 3.15V.

This is a diagram:

[image]

Am I missing something?

PS when connected through USB it links to the Wifi and all works fine.

Comment: Is the on board 3.3V regulator getting hot? What if you adjust the regulator board while under load not no load.

Comment: Can you connect an ammeter to the 9v source to see how the current demand changes with load versus no load?

Comment: @Passerby Is the on board 3.3V regulator getting hot? No it is not getting hot. What if you adjust the regulator board while under load not no load? adjust to what value?

Comment: @raaymaan Under no load: 0.5 mA and under load 22.2 mA

Answer (score 1):

D1 Mini and the ESP8266 requires a surprising amount of current. Over 200 mA at times - easy for USB but perhaps too much for your small 5 V regulator. It's not like an an Atmega Arduino!

If you're having trouble with it not booting, it's almost certainly the power supply being too weak.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment stating the current draw is 20mA when loaded, this seems like it is within normal operating limits.

I found the following schematic from [this website](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/d1/d1_mini.html). It's probably not identical to your "D1 mini" going by picture alone, but I expect they're functionally the same.

1. The regulator, listed here as a [ME6211C33](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6211C33M5G-N_C82942.pdf), has a absolute maximum input voltage of 6.5V - be careful with adjustable power supplies, and take the time to look at the voltage ripple. Your DMM will average the readings but an oscilloscope will give a much clearer picture. 5v coming from USB will be about 5.25v (Off the top of my head, I have not checked the USB spec)
2. Have a look at U4, [CH340](https://www.mpja.com/download/35227cpdata.pdf), a USB to serial chip. This is connected to the ESP8266 - there could be some sort of handshaking needed before it can fully boot. An easy way to disprove this would be to hack an old USB cable and cut the D+ and D-wires (or lift the D+ D- legs of U4) so that you're still providing a clean power source.

[image]